# Etymology of "marketing:" how/when did it change meaning?

Tags: etymology, historical-change, errors

The [best etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=marketing) I could find says the definition of marketing has changed like this:

> 1560s, "buying and selling," verbal noun from market (v.). Meaning
>   "produce bought at a market" is from 1701. The business sense,
>   "process of moving goods from producer to consumer with emphasis on
>   advertising and sales," is attested by 1897.

Is there any more detail about how/why the current meaning started being used and why the older meanings fell out of common usage?

---

**update:**

The etymology above lists the three different meanings; here are some more details:

- The first [wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/marketing#Noun) is: "Buying and selling in a market."
- Related question: [Have you done your marketing today?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/have-you-done-your-marketing-today)

I never knew "marketing" had these other meanings until I started looking into its etymology. I always thought marketing meant something related to promoting goods/services for sale. I never thought it had anything to do with consumption, too.

Comment: What do you mean by "current meaning"?  And what "older meanings" do you feel have "fallen out of common usage"??

Comment: @HotLicks: I added a clarification.

Comment: to non native speakers "marketing" is a term that was adopted by most languages around the world after it became a management discipline ('60s/'70s) In English it has retained also it original meaning which is not used outside English  speaking countries.

Comment: @HotLicks: Also marketing and sales are usually seen as two different activities, but sales is a part of dictionary marketing.

Comment: When a farmer goes to sell his crop he's "marketing" it.  I regularly hear the word used in that sense here, in corn country.  Consider that the word is based on the word "market", which is a place (tangible or intangible) where goods are bought and sold.  Use of the term to mean advertising & promoting is a bit of a perversion of the meaning.

Comment: (It's still unclear what you're asking.  The "old" meaning of the term remains perfectly vital, and the "new" meaning has not really changed in 50 years or so.)

Comment: The question is based on a mistaken belief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [American Maketing Association](http://www.uriel.org/brand-management/the-origin-of-the-marketing-concept/) website , marketing as a discipline  emerged in the U.S.A. in the '50s:

> - After the second world war, in 1950, the service economy first employed more than 50 percent of the US population. ***Marketing’s modern origins as a normative management discipline emerged in the 1950s (Baker, 1999).***  Baker (1974, 1991) presented a broad treatment of marketing definitions which positions marketing as a hybrid management field intertwined from microeconomics, statistical mathematics and psychology. Brand Management has been couched by marketing management to a great extent.